# Property $x(t)\otimes \delta (t-t_0)=x(t_0)$

Tags: education, convolution, dirac-delta

My professor said that:

$$x(t)\otimes \delta (t-t_0)=x(t_0)$$

How can I prove it? I tried to apply the definition of convolution $q(x)w(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{q(\tau)w(x-\tau)d\tau}$:

$$x(t)\otimes \delta (t-t_0)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{x(\tau)\delta (t-t_0-\tau)d\tau}$$

Then I applied the sifting property $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{q(x)\delta(x-a)dx=q(a)}$:

$$x(t)\otimes \delta (t-t_0)=x(t_0+\tau)$$

What is wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that the result you get cannot depend on the integration variable $\tau$ that you have integrated over. You probably picked the wrong "$a$": you should have taken $a = t-t_0$ not $a = t_0-\tau$.

Comment: Hello @Winther. What do you mean? I have $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{x(\tau)\delta (t-t_0-\tau)d\tau}=x(t_0+\tau)$, this is the application of sifting property thus should be right.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(\tau) \, \delta (t-t_0-\tau) \, d\tau = x(t_0-t)$$

Comment: Note that $\delta(-x) = \delta(x)$ so your integral (which is over $\tau$) is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau) \delta(\tau - \color{red}{(t-t_0)}){\rm d}\tau$. Now use what you know about the $\delta$-function.

Comment: Thank you so much @Winther.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\tau$ is your integration variable, so it should disappear in your result. And your convolution is not defined properly. I think what is meant is you look at the "functions"
$$
f(t) = x(t), \quad g(t) = \delta(t - t_{0})
$$
and then at the convolution $(f \otimes g)(t)$.

I would be surprised if the result was independent of $t$ as your professor said, since if we do not shift by $t_{0}$ we get 
$$
(x \otimes \delta )(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x(\tau) \delta(t - \tau) d \tau = x(t),
$$
by the definition of the $\delta$ distribution and its "symmetry" $\delta(-x) = \delta(x)$.

For the more general case we have
\begin{align*}
(f \otimes g)(t) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} x(\tau) \delta ((t - \tau) - t_{0}) d \tau = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x(\tau) \delta ((t - t_{0}) - \tau) d \tau \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} x(\tau) \delta (\tau- (t - t_{0})) d \tau= x(t - t_{0}).
\end{align*}